# Image can't be decoded while displaying big image

Tags: android, android-image, universal-image-loader

I am unable to load big image in [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

My code

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = null;
    try {
        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(this, Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                this).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache());

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageLoader
            .displayImage(
                    "http://www.kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/images/100mm/IMG_1906.JPG",
                    imageView1, new ImageLoadingListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1,
                                FailReason arg2) {
                            Log.e("", "" + arg2);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0,
                                View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0,
                                View arg1) {
                        }
                    });
```

I am getting error like this

```
09-27 14:13:00.982: E/ImageLoader(31251): Image can't be decoded [http://www.kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/images/100mm/IMG_1906.JPG_1080x1920]
```

I am able to load other images only this image can not b loaded.may be it size is above 5 MB. So how can I load big image using UIL. Is there any alternative way to sort out this?

Comment: any more log ? a stacktrace, may be ?

Comment: `http://www.kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/images/100mm/IMG_1906.JPG_1080x1920` does not exist, and is not what you call in your code. are you sure this is the code you use ?

Comment: also, this image is huge, and could easily cause an out of memory

Comment: I think it may throw out of memory error even if you able to downlod it

Comment: It does not show any more log for failer. failed resonn comes `null`.

Comment: is there any decode file function in imageLoader class ?

Comment: i have tried your image link in browser the problem is **_1080x1920** after the JPG extension

Comment: @MuhammadBabar If you are aware of UIL. When UIL throw exception, It just prints dimensions at end of path.

Comment: I had the same problem, it was because the external SDCard of the phone had a problem, the library coudn't write on it.

Comment: @sunshine Thanks for this comment: If you are aware of UIL. When UIL throw exception, It just prints dimensions at end of path.

Answer (score -3):

The resource in http://www.kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/images/100mm/IMG_1906.JPG_1080x1920 is a Image is not a image?